# Transformation of Data Issue - Power Query

Tags: powerquery

[image]

I am struggling to transform my dataset in power query, it is 260,000 rows (I have simplified to 17 here for the example)

I need to be able to extrapolate the data out to have all entry numbers by entity.

For visual representation you can see in the middle section how it would look with every entry number.

Then I need to fill those blanks with repeating data until the next date.

Any suggestions would be amazing as I have been sitting working on this one for so many hours to no avail.

---

Update
let
Source = Table.NestedJoin(#"ENTITY | DATE", {"Entity"}, #"MAX ENTRY NO", {"Entity"}, "MAX ENTRY NO", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded MAX ENTRY NO" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "MAX ENTRY NO", {"Max Entry No.1"}, {"Max Entry No.1"}),
#"Changed column type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded MAX ENTRY NO", {{"Entity", type text}, {"Creation Date", type date}, {"From Entry No", Int64.Type}, {"Max Entry No.1", Int64.Type}})
,
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed column type", {"Entity"}, {{"From Entry No", each {List.Min([From Entry No]).. List.Max([Max Entry No.1])}}}),
#"Expanded FROM ENTRY NO" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "From Entry No"),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded FROM ENTRY NO", {"Entity", "From Entry No"}, Source, {"Entity", "From Entry No"}, "Table1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table1", {"Creation Date", "Max Entry No.1"}, {"Creation Date", "Max Entry No.1"}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded Table1",{{"Entity", Order.Ascending}, {"From Entry No", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Sorted Rows",{"Creation Date", "Max Entry No.1"}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filled Down",{{"Creation Date", type date}})
in #"Changed Type"
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Explain please why the imputed entry number between 3 and 5 is 3, and why the entry numbers between seven and eleven are 5,6,7,8,9,10

Comment: Typos - should just be 1,2,3,4,5,6 - sequential for all.

Comment: Did any of these answers solve your issue? If so, please accept one to close out question

Comment: I'm not sure yet

Comment: Your columns have different names then my example. Match them, including spacing and capitalization

Comment: last screenshot added and I got it to work, thank you! - now have 61 million rows to extract :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate method

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"COMPANY"}, {{"FROM ENTRY NO", each {List.Min([FROM ENTRY NO]).. List.Max([MAX ENTRY NO])}}}),
#"Expanded FROM ENTRY NO" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "FROM ENTRY NO"),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded FROM ENTRY NO", {"COMPANY", "FROM ENTRY NO"}, Source, {"COMPANY", "FROM ENTRY NO"}, "Table1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table1", {"CREATION DATE", "MAX ENTRY NO"}, {"CREATION DATE", "MAX ENTRY NO"}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded Table1",{{"COMPANY", Order.Ascending}, {"FROM ENTRY NO", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Sorted Rows",{"CREATION DATE", "MAX ENTRY NO"}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filled Down",{{"CREATION DATE", type date}})
in #"Changed Type"
```

Potentially faster, since work done within groups

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"COMPANY"}, {{"data", each 
    let  #"AddMissing"= _&Table.FromList(List.Difference({List.Min(_[FROM ENTRY NO]).. List.Max(_[MAX ENTRY NO])},_[FROM ENTRY NO]),Splitter.SplitByNothing(), {"FROM ENTRY NO"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"AddMissing",{{"FROM ENTRY NO", Order.Ascending}})
    in Table.FillDown(#"Sorted Rows",{"COMPANY", "CREATION DATE", "MAX ENTRY NO"})
, type table [COMPANY=text, CREATION DATE=nullable date, FROM ENTRY NO=number, MAX ENTRY NO=number]}}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"CREATION DATE", "FROM ENTRY NO", "MAX ENTRY NO"}, {"CREATION DATE", "FROM ENTRY NO", "MAX ENTRY NO"})
in #"Expanded data"
```

Comment: If I am doing this correctly, checking the run times in Power BI, using the Excel table as a data source, this algorithm is quite a bit slower than mine. With 260,000 rows, it might make a significant difference.

Comment: Could very well be. Didn't test it. Thanks for the assistance

Comment: Second version is probably faster since operations are within groups

Comment: I tried using the first block, what I achieved is in the original question now as an update, any ideas what I have done wrong please?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have typos in your results pictures, the following may do what you want.

Read the code comments for algorithm explanation.

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table28"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"COMPANY", type text}, {"CREATION DATE", type date}, {"FROM ENTRY NO", Int64.Type}, {"MAX ENTRY NO", Int64.Type}}),

//Group by company
    #"Group By Company" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type",{"COMPANY"},{
        {"Repeats", (t)=> 
            let 

    //generate table with rows repeated for each difference between successive FROM ENTRY NO's
    //  except for the final entry which is based on the difference between the FROM and MAX NO's
                #"Repeated Rows"=
                    List.Generate(
                        ()=>[rws=List.Repeat({t{0}}, t[FROM ENTRY NO]{1}-t[FROM ENTRY NO]{0}), idx=0],
                        each [idx]<Table.RowCount(t),
                        each [rws= try List.Repeat({t{[idx]+1}}, t[FROM ENTRY NO]{[idx]+2} - t[FROM ENTRY NO]{[idx]+1})
                            otherwise List.Repeat({t{[idx]+1}}, t[MAX ENTRY NO]{[idx]+1} - t[FROM ENTRY NO]{[idx]+1} + 1),
                            idx=[idx]+1],
                        each Table.FromRecords([rws])),

            //Add an Index column starting at the first FROM no to each Company sub table
            //  This will be the same as the FROM no.
            //  So we can replace the FROM column with the Index column
        
                #"Add Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Table.Combine(#"Repeated Rows"),"Index",(t)[FROM ENTRY NO]{0},1,Int64.Type),
                #"Remove FROM" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Add Index",{"FROM ENTRY NO"}),
                #"Rename Index" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Remove FROM",{{"Index","FROM ENTRY NO"}}),
                #"Reorder Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Rename Index",Table.ColumnNames(t))
            in 
                #"Reorder Columns", type table[COMPANY=text,CREATION DATE=date, FROM ENTRY NO=Int64.Type, MAX ENTRY NO=Int64.Type]    
            }}),
            
    #"Expanded Repeats" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Group By Company", "Repeats", {"CREATION DATE", "FROM ENTRY NO", "MAX ENTRY NO"}, {"CREATION DATE", "FROM ENTRY NO", "MAX ENTRY NO"})
in
    #"Expanded Repeats"
```

***Data***
[image]

***Results***
[image]